# If I have a folder with many code snippet folders, how to avoid Git or Mercurial from committing source code in another folder?

Tags: git, mercurial, dvcs

If I have a folder such as:

```
code/try_closure
code/try_http_send
  [...]
```

I can create a repository at the `code` folder, but then if I commit at the `try_http_send` folder:

```
hg commit -m "good version"      <--- git should be similar
```

then, I can accidentally commit other code changes in *all* other folders under `code`.

Alternatively, I can create repositories for each of the sub-folders, but that's kind of silly and what if I need to push the whole `code` to another location, then I need to push sub-folders one by one?  Is there a way to solve this?  The keyword here is "accidentally" commit all files in other sub-folders.  I know I can use  `hg commit . -m "good version"`, but it is just so easy to do `hg commit -m "..."` instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make them separate repositories and then make them [subrepositories](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/Subrepository) of a top level code module.  Then within code you can do `hg push --subrepos` to push them all, and then can be clones as tree as well.

Comment: by the way when I type `hg push --subrepos` it says 
`hg push: option --subrepos not recognized`  maybe just need to say push and it will push all sub repos, and commit or push when current directory is the sub repo, then it will only commit or push that sub repo

Comment: You pr0bably need a newer version of Mercurial. I don't think that option showed up until 1.7.

Answer (score 1):

A repository should contain things that you want to commit together. If you never want to commit code from separate folders together, each folder should be a separate repository.

Comment: "A repository should contain things that you want to commit together"...  is it true for git and hg?  Who said it?  While it might be usually true, I think it might be like saying, "a program should take user's input, process it, and output the results"  while true most of the time, what about a program that gives a random quote, in which case, there is no real user input, just processing and output, and a video game in an arcade game center, there is output even before any user input (to attract people to put in money)

Comment: also, if they really should belong to all different repositories, then is there a way to push `code` folder all in one command?  It would be silly to need to push every single folder or even write a script to do it.

Comment: Both Git and Hg track changesets at the repository level, not the file/directory level. It's true due to the inherent nature of how they work...

Answer (score 0):

Seriously, you should spend that time for the period. Besides that, it's always a good idea to check what your next commit is going to do, e.g. by using `hg st` and `hg diff`. Such a check acts as a last quick review for the work to commit and possibly reminds you to commit some files only (e.g. `.`). Unless you want to *snapshot* current work, you shouldn't commit blindly.

That said, if you really want to commit without file arguments you could either

- use subrepos as suggested in other answers, or
- define a commit [alias](http://www.selenic.com/mercurial/hgrc.5.html#alias) with `.` as a default argument

Comment: sometimes it is just too easy to:  make a tiny change, or even just a comment change, and you think it is just a tiny change and it is ok, and go ahead with `hg com -m "change comment"` and commit everything